# Draw Triangle on top of Rectangle in Java

Tags: java

Super newbie here. I am trying to draw a Triangle on top of the Rectangles I draw but it does not appear. I know it is there because when I remove the 2 Rectangles and change the color to Yellow or something, it appears. I also need to put stars and sun on top of the Triangle... and yes it is a flag. I am not asking for the exact code. Hints for newbies will be appreciated. Please help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FlagShapes extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        //triangle of the flag
        int[] xPoints={75, 75, 130};
        int[] yPoints={75, 185, 130};
        int nPoints=3;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);

        //blue part of the flag
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(75, 75, 200, 55);

        //red part of the flag
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(75, 130, 200, 55);

        //pole drawing
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(72, 75, 2, 300);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the answer to my question (thanks Yahoo) Java's default rendering approach uses rasterisation. Just draw the two shapes in the same location Java will draw both even if they overlap. Whichever one is drawn first will be 'under' whichever one is drawn second.